# Python XLwings writing COUNTIF formula in a cell

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using XLwings to write in my excel file. I need to write the formal `=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)` in a cell in excel.

I am doingthe following, my code is working fine before adding     `overview_sheet.range('A9').formula = '=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)'`

```
import xlwings as xw
...
wb = xw.Book(template)
ws = wb.sheets['warnings']
overview_sheet = wb.sheets['Overview']
overview_sheet.range('A9').formula = '=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)'
...
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XX/XXX/XXX/Main.py", line 109, in <module>
    overview_sheet.range('A9').value = '=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)'
```

if I write a simple formula like '`=SUM(1;3)'` it works , but with my COUNTIF formula not

How can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Excel so your formula may be valid, however to me it does not match the COUNTIF function syntax of =COUNTIF(<range>, <criteria>) and if I just paste your formula into a cell it is rejected as being an incorrect formula. Any 'correct' =COUNTIF formula I enter into a cell using your code works OK.

However assuming the formula is how you want it; from a few tests it seems xlwings rejects the line when it is determined to be a formula i.e. if the preceding '=' exists, so removing the = allows the formula to be written without error to cell, but of course won't do anything.
Since the formula in any cell is just text an alternative to writing to the cell would be to use '.value'

```
overview_sheet.range('A9').value = '=COUNTIF(...)'
```

Using '.value' instead of '.formula' allows the formula to be written without error however Excel converts it to text by placing a single quote in front so this may be why you are using .formula.

The following might be a work around.
I can't confirm it will absolutely work since as stated Excel rejects your formula as having incorrect syntax. However if it is valid for your sheet you can try making use of xlwings cell edit feature and write to the cell this way;
Put a character in front of the formula, it should be able to be any character that Excel would not otherwise recognise as another cell function, I have used 'X' in the example. This allow the formula to be written without error. Then on the next line of code, remove the first character 'X' from the cell leaving the formula as you want it. This again should complete without error and the sheet can then be saved.

```
overview_sheet.range('A9').value = "X=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)"
overview_sheet.range('A9').characters[0].api.Delete()
```

In my sheet the formula is changed by Excel to text again

```
'=COUNTIF(warnings!$F:$F;1)
```

but if its a valid formula on your sheet it may not be changed.

---

Additional details
Refresh the worksheet (F9)

```
overview_sheet.api.Calculate()
```

Change the formula calculation option to manual and back to auto

```
wb.api.Calculation = -4135  # -4135 is xlCalculationManual 
wb.api.Calculation = -4105  # -4105 is xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, at least I can see the text of the formula. but the issue is that this needs an "Enter on the formula to work. when I manually press "Enter in the formula, it works. any Idea how to make an Enter on the formula?""

Comment: maybe you can replace the formula by "=SUM(1;3)" to see if it's working for you. for me it needs an enter

Comment: Using "=SUM(1:3)", with colon not semicolon like other 'valid' formula doesn't need any additional interaction on my testing. Perhaps you can try a sheet refresh (F9) and/or setting the formula calculation on the workbook to manual and back to automatic. I've added the code for these to the bottom of the answer above.

Comment: how can I do the sheet refresh? :-s

Comment: Look at the 'Additional Details' at bottom of answer above.

Comment: doesn't work. it doesn't update the formula bar. an enter on the formula bar is missing

Comment: Hitting 'return' programatically equates to pasting the formula in the cell which takes you back to the original issue. Sorry I cannot think of any other options to try at this time.