# Openpyxl formula cells shown as empty when opened in Excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

When I save formulas using openpyxl and open the file in Excel, the formula cells are empty. If I click on the cell, I see the formula is there, I have to click enter to resave the formula, only then Excel will show the actual value.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

sheet['A1'] = 10
sheet['A2'] = "=SUM(A1)"
sheet["A3"] = "=SUM(1, 1)"

book.save("/tmp/sample.xlsx")
```

I've tried searching for examples of how to use formulas, but they are the same as my solution.

Apparently, openpyxl marks the formula cells as needing recalculation and Excel calculates them when opened. For some reason, this process doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, Openpyxl just puts in the cell the text you put in the quotes. It doesn't know if it's a number, text, formula or other, its just a value. If the the formulas do nothing until the workbook is refreshed would appear to a problem with your Excel.

Comment: I have the latest Microsoft Excel version (16.67) for MacOS. I tried opening it in Numbers and everything works properly. However, I've never had any other problems with my Excel. And I need to distribute this file, so it would be nice to know that it works for everybody.

Comment: When you say "I need to distribute this file" are you talking about the 'sample.xlsx' in your question or another file that you are writing complex formulas to? Certainly if the formula is complex or makes complex references you may experience this, but not for the simple formulas in 'sample.xlsx'. In regards to your it works fine for me on Windows Excel, I'm not aware that Mac has any specific issues in this respect.

Comment: I need to distribute a much larger file with similarly complex formulas. Lots of =E10/F10 and so on. I ended up doing it in Python, which is not a problem,  but I wanted to add the formulas so people can actually check how things are calculated.

Comment: You could try to open and refresh the sheet in Excel to see if that does the trick but no guarantee. You'd have to use something like Xlwings to do that, see **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490018/python-xlwings-writing-countif-formula-in-a-cell/72554395#72554395** for details if you want to try, didn't work for the poster. Even just pasting the formula(s) in Excel using Xlwings instead also might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's not a viable option for me. The file is generated on a Linux instance in AWS Lambda. I'd have to jump through lots of hoops just to refresh it.

Comment: I tried the exact same code again and somehow now everything works, including complex formulas in large spreadsheets. I don't remember updating or changing anything. Go figure...

Comment: Glad to hear it came good.